# Italics for some labels in pie chart R

Tags: r, pie-chart, typography

I have a pie chart of counts for 4 species. The names of Sp1, Sp2, and Sp3 should be italicized, and Sp4 should be plain text.

```
Speciesa <- c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4")
Counts <- c(2, 3, 14, 3)
pie(Counts, Speciesa, col=colors, cex=1.2, init.angle=46)
```

Adds italics to all

```
pie(Counts, Speciesa, col=colors, font=3)
```

I'm having difficulty calling a command that does not italicize all of the labels. I've tried entering the Species names with the (italics) call, but this was unsuccessful.

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with this a bit more and figured out a solution. Keeping this up in case anyone else has the same issue.

```
Speciesb <- c(expression(italic("Sp1")), 
expression(italic("Sp 2")),
expression(italic("Sp3")), "Sp4")

Countsb <- c(2, 3,14,3)
pie(Countsb, Speciesb, cex=1.2, init.angle=46)
```